# Как подменить src видео после его проигрывания

Tags: html, массивы, видео

Есть 3 видео, нужно сделать чтобы они игрались в одном и том же окне, друг за другом автоматически, через onended отдельной функцией решил этот вопрос,но мне кажется это не совсем корректно т.к. итогово будет 9 видео и для каждого писать функцию это слишком коряво... Как решить эту проблему? На ум приходит создать массив видео, но как заставить плеер отображать конкретный элемент (в данном случае видео) а после завершения его проигрывания переходить на следующий? Так же подскажите почему не работает атрибут autoplay? Пробовал в хроме и MsEdge... Спасибо.

Comment: Так не пишите отделенный скрипт для каждого видео. Создайте цикл

Comment: Как обратиться к кнокретному шагу цикла в функции?

Answer (score 0):

По поводу автоплея почитайте тут https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#Autoplay_availability , может поможет. Браузеры сейчас ввели ограничение на автоплей, надо соблюдать их рекомендации что б запускать видео

```js
var video;
var _this;
var videos = $('.videoClass').length;
var i = 1;
$('.videoClass').each(function() {
  this.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    _this = $(this);
    if (i < videos) {
      $('.active').next().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.video').first().addClass('active');
      i = 0;
    }
    _this.parents('.video').removeClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      video = $('.active').find('.videoClass')[0];
      video.play();
    }, 70);
    i++;
  }, false);
});
```

```css
.video {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

video {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video active">
  <video id="video_1" class="videoClass" preload="auto" controls="controls" autoplay muted> 
        <source src="https://katekostuk.github.io/Projects/xil/video/1146-halo_5_guardians_the_hunt_begins_mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
<div class="video">
  <video id="video_2" class="videoClass" preload="auto" controls="controls" muted> 
        <source src="https://katekostuk.github.io/Projects/xil/video/1146-halo_5_guardians_the_hunt_begins_mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
<div class="video">
  <video id="video_3" class="videoClass" preload="auto" controls="controls" muted>  
        <source src="https://katekostuk.github.io/Projects/xil/video/1146-halo_5_guardians_the_hunt_begins_mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
```